# Not able to build Okular from source

Tags: cmake, kde-plasma, okular

I want to change something very simple in okular and may be I can do it myself by changing the source.

I have the source code from Github [ https://github.com/KDE/okular ]. It does not have a README and nowhere in the code I found anything about build procedure.

But here [ http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/kde/okular5.html ] I found some commands to build it from source. These are the commands :-

```
mkdir build &&
cd    build &&

cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$KF5_PREFIX \
      -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release         \
      -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF                \
      -Wno-dev .. &&
make
```

But when I ran these I got following :-

[image]

Any ideas what is the issue? How can I build okular?

Will be thankful for any help.

Comment: Please, post the configuration log as a **text**, not as *image*. See [ask].

Comment: I am not getting the error now so cannot copy paste text, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing extra-cmake-modules, a package from KDE Frameworks 5. This package is available in every linux distro that ships KDE. You'll need more -devel/-dev packages other than ECM.

Take a look at http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/kde/extra-cmake-modules.html for details, and chapter 30 too.

The okular site (https://okular.kde.org) will also guide you to build from source.